# Update data for multiple select for multiple value

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel-5.3

```
<select name="eng_country[]" class="form-control">
```

print_r($_POST['eng_country']);exit;

> ```
> through this i am getting output like:
> ```

```
 Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 [2] => 2 )
```

> ```
> after this i did :
> ```

```
foreach ($_POST['eng_country'] as $key => $value) {
                 $data = [   
                'table' =>  'tbl_worker_exp',
                'val'=>array(
                'country_id'=>$value),
                'where' =>  ['sub_id'=>$id]
            ];

             }
 $result=update($data);
```

> ```
> my table like:
> ```

```
    id  sub_id          data        
    1   2                 2                 
    2   2                 1                 
    3   2                 4                 
    4   1                 4
```

> i want to change my data field from what value i am getting from the
>   html select option but in my case its updated data as the last get
>   value .. please help me related this .

Update query is:

```
function update($data)
    {
           $UpdateDB=DB::table($data['table'])
            ->where($data['where'])
            ->update($data['val']);
            return  $UpdateDB;
    }
```

Comment: No, you lost me. Please update the question with more details, its certainly not clear.

Comment: my question is that how can i update the data in case of foreach data

Comment: Aniket Sahrawat@ any solution ??

Comment: make $data a Array and push all the values, call update function while looping the $data  array

Comment: can u please update my question ??

Comment: what is $id in 'where' =>  ['sub_id'=>$id]?

Comment: here i am getting $id =2  and want only sub_id=2 fields to update

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($_POST['eng_country'] as $key => $value) {
             $data = [   
            'table' =>  'tbl_worker_exp',
            'val'=>array(
            'country_id'=>$value),
            'where' =>  ['sub_id'=>$id]
        ];
  $result=update($data); //keep the update function inside the loop
  }
```

Comment: not working its taking only array last value and updated all filds as last value...

Comment: i have used the same concept and it is working fine https://3v4l.org/F8fGn

Comment: loop is not iterating in my case it take the last value and update all the fields

Comment: take a look at https://3v4l.org/WrrpT  i have not knowledge of laravel so the problem maybe inside the array iteration